# Spin drift velocity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, diffusion, quantum-statistics

I am currently reading this [Phys Rev paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.104.563) by H C Torrey. In this paper, he derives the Bloch equations with an additional diffusion term. He says that the current density is given by 
$$\mathbf j_{\pm} = n_{\pm} \mathbf V_{\pm} - D \nabla n_{\pm},$$
where $n$ is the number of spins(up/down).

Now the second term is clear, as this one comes from [Fick's first law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick's_laws_of_diffusion), but the first one is strange. He claims that $\mathbf V_{\pm}$ is the velocity of positively(negatively) oriented spins (he restricts himself to spin 1/2). Does anybody know what this drift velocity could mean?

Comment: Could you send the paper somehow? I am unable to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drift velocity means velocity due to the magnetic field gradient acting upon the particle having the spin.

This reference may be helpful: http://people.duke.edu/~ad159/files/p142/4.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the paper but I can speculate...

One possible reason for drift is a very obvious one: If the nuclei are drifting, then they will carry their spins with them. For example, if the nucleon is part of a molecule in blood, and the blood is flowing down an artery, then the spin will flow down the artery too.